# Is it possible to write to an existing csv file in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an event that exports the stock of products from the database every week. 1 Column is the product_id and the other one is the stock of products at the begging of the week. Is it possible to write a query that creates a new column in this file with the stock at the end of the week ?

Thanks in advance!

Couldn't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to write to an existing csv file in MySQL?

Noway.

> .. an event that exports the stock of products at the begging of the week .. a new column in this file with the stock at the end of the week

For your particular task: you may create one file at the week beginning, and at the week end you may load it into temptable, add needed columns, and save this result into another file.